# kdb q - group table within partition

Tags: kdb

Starting from a fresh partition `mydb` I am saving the following three tables `table1`, `table2`, `table3` in partitions `2018.01.01`, `2018.01.02`, `2018.01.03`, respectively:

```
npertable:10000000;

table1:([]date:npertable?2018.01.01+til 25;acc:npertable?`C123`C132`C321`C121`C131;c:npertable?til 100);
table2:([]date:npertable?2018.02.01+til 25;acc:npertable?`C123`C132`C321`C121`C131;c:npertable?til 100);
table3:([]date:npertable?2018.03.01+til 25;acc:npertable?`C123`C132`C321`C121`C131;c:npertable?til 100);

table1:`date xasc table1;
table2:`date xasc table2;
table3:`date xasc table3;

`:mydb/2018.01.01/t/ set .Q.en[`:mydb;table1];
`:mydb/2018.01.02/t/ set .Q.en[`:mydb;table2];
`:mydb/2018.01.03/t/ set .Q.en[`:mydb;table3];
```

You can see that I have different `acc` groups that I will later select on.
When I sort the tables before storing additionally by `acc` I get a slight speedup (253 vs 391 milliseconds). So if I later want to query

```
select from t where date=2018.01.01, acc=`C123
```

is sorting by `acc` before storing the best I can do? Or is there something in storing the partitions that will create an index for the different `acc` groups?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You may want to consider a different partition scheme - while the typical approach is to partition by date, and then part by sym within each partition, depending on how your data will be queried this may not always be the best approach. For example, if you're typically querying for a given `acc`, it might be best to partition by this field (you can only partition by int, but this could be an enumeration of this field), and part by date within the partitions. You can see a bit more explanation in this post on our blog: https://www.aquaq.co.uk/q/kdb-iot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the parted attribute for optimizing your queries. 
For example you can use this bit to sort by acc and apply the attribute.

```
{@[`acc xasc .Q.par[`:mydb;x;`t];`acc;`p#]}'[2018.01.01 2018.01.02 2018.01.03]
```

For more details about the parted attribute and its effects you can read this whitepaper from KX -> https://kx.com/media/2017/11/Columnar_database_and_query_optimization.pdf

Also please be aware that you can use a month partition to suit your needs. 
If I properly understand your example you have `year.day.month` so you can reduce this to `year.month` if day will always be `01`
i.e Instead of using

```
`:mydb/2018.01.01/t/ set .Q.en[`:mydb;table1];
```

you can simply use

```
`:mydb/2018.01/t/ set .Q.en[`:mydb;table1];
```

You can find more details about achieving this here -> https://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/partitioned_tables#1.3.7.2_Monthly

Comment: I don't think `"D$raze string x` is necessary, surely this can be just `x`?

Comment: I think I left it there by mistake. Thank for pointing that out. I will modify it now.